# Noob ! jQuery double clicking issue and simplify code

Tags: jquery

I have two pictures with a bottom button which is slide up and down showing some text contain and is working.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="ca-item-main span4">
     <div class="ca-icon"></div>
        <a href="#" class="moreDetails">More Details</a>
       <div class="content"> <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor </p></div>
</div>
<div class="ca-item-main span4">
     <div class="ca-icon"></div>
        <a href="#" class="moreDetails-2">More Details</a>
       <div class="content-2"> <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor </p></div>
</div>
```

I am a noob with jQuery so I need a simple solution to fix two problems:

1 - Mouse Click is working always second time. I need to double-click, to make slide work.

2 - How to simplify this jquery code ?

jQuery Code:

```
$('.moreDetails, .content').toggle(function(){
    $('.moreDetails, .content').animate({'bottom':0});
}, function(){
    $('.moreDetails, .content').animate({'bottom':190});
});

$('.moreDetails-2, .content-2').toggle(function(){
    $('.moreDetails-2, .content-2').animate({'bottom':0});
}, function(){
    $('.moreDetails-2, .content-2').animate({'bottom':190});
});
```

Thanks for any good solution.

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you're asking here. Could we see the "wrapper" HTML around what is there, or could you recreate this in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You might also look [***here***](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/#example-0)

Comment: All you people negging with 0 feedback ... yea, you're a real great help to the community. And you wonder why there are more and more people starting to hate this site. If you're gonna neg, at least give this poor guy a good reason, or vote to close with a reason that will be given where he can see it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the reason why its working the second time is probably because the bottom css initially is 0, therefore you dont see any difference when clicking first. but since you did not provide a js fiddle or css, its only a guess.
   2.) toggle is a deprecated event. use .click() instead and do an if statement, checking for classes for example:

   $('.moreDetails, .content').click(
   // if hasClass('foobar')
   // ..
   // else
   // ..
   );